# Best approach to report multiple t-test results in an abstract

Tags: t-test, reporting

Abstracts require a comprehensive summary of a paper's contents, usually within a 150-250 word limit.

In my study, I used the paired t-test to compare the mean height of two groups from two different samples. Results show significant differences in the means and a large effect size between the two groups of those two samples. So same results.

If it was one sample, I could report the results like this:

There was a significant difference in height between Group 1 (M = Mean, SD = standard deviation) and Group 2 (M = Mean, SD = standard deviation); t(df) = t-value, p = p-value.

But for two samples, how can I report the results in one sentence in an abstract?

Comment: There is no correct answer. I advise looking at published articles in that journal or similar journals in that field.

Comment: It's usually not necessary to put all relevant statistics into an Abstract.